# Returning specific date format with Jackson

Tags: json, datetime, jackson, jersey-2.0

I am trying to return the date on the json object as a specific format:
This is the format:

"lastModified": "2015-08-04T13:09:15.000-07:00",

I have a custom ObjectMapper which do this:

```
result.setDateFormat(new ISO8601DateFormat());
```

But this result:
"lastModified": "2015-08-04T20:09:15Z"

any ideas how to change it?
I am using:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.1</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

and before that I used an older version of:
org.codehaus.jackson

**Update:**
After adding this line:

```
result.configure(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature.
        WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS , false);
```

and removed:

```
result.setDateFormat(new ISO8601DateFormat());
```

I got the result:
    "lastModified": "2015-08-04T20:09:15.000+0000",
which is still not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This the right format:

```
result.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"));
```